# Asking about team recommendations

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

In [summoners-war](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/summoners-war) it is often the case that you need a specific team composition in order to tackle a dungeon.

Let's say you have 20 high-level monsters in your list and want to ask about which of them are suitable to pass the Giants B10 dungeon (very commonly asked on reddit and official forums). Or you want to advance further in the Trial of Ascension and are stuck on a floor and seek help by getting some recommendations of what monsters are suitable for your situation.

It pretty much looks like it's too opinion based. Some people would tell you to use monsters A and B, other people recommend something else (maybe A and C) and both recs would actually work, but is it on-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had an issue [with this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321556/setup-for-giants-keep) a while back and I guess it's alright now, but it's still not good. The questions inherently are broad because there are a lot of monsters to choose from in this game. It's a similar issue we face when discussing League of Legends meta questions about champions or items.

The correct (IMO) to ask these questions are:

1. State your issue. Example: I'm dying from this attack because this.
2. State what you are looking to accomplish. Example: I'm looking to mitigate the damage OR I'm looking to kill the monster before X attack goes off.
3. Give a precise list of available monsters + current team, but don't make the list too long because it can become unnecessary information. Example: I'm using A, B, C, D and E but I also have Z, Y, X that I think could be useful. Answers can also suggest 1 or 2 more monsters in this case as it would be useful for others who have those monsters.
4. EXPLAIN why this would help. Example: Monster A and B do this better and that is the mechanic that is most useful in this situation.

There are ways to take broad subjects and dive just deep enough for it to be useful for others.

Number 1 gives clear explanation about why the issue is happening and can't be considered broad.

Number 2 goes into your research and provides examples of someone trying to solve it. This can lead to an answer that solves the issue right here at number 2, because the asker didn't know about something that might be helpful.

Number 3 are the resources provided to help the answer-er(-er-er) pinpoint something that might help. Makes the question more legit IMO.

Number 4 makes the answer acceptable instead of just saying "dur, spend money, get best monsters and win the game"

Comment: Yea, it's pretty broad when I ask "What team do I need for XY?" and should probably be closed for that reason, unless it's a starter team (those are usually the same 4-5 monsters for everyone). With the rest I agree.. a list of monsters owned is very important unless someone asks what to farm with priority. And explanations.. I always forget them, although they're important.